# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bunch of code. When I add the details, i dont know why I am getting error as *Input string was not in a correct format.*

at this line

**cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();**

Please see the code for your reference:-

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_expense_category (NgoId,expense_category_name,expense_category_description,active) values(@NgoId,@expense_category_name, @expense_category_description,@active)", conn);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@NgoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlNgoName.SelectedValue;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@expense_category_name", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtExpenseCat.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@expense_category_description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEspenseDesc.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkActive.Checked;
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Expenses added sucessfully');window.location ='csrexpensecategorylist.aspx';", true);
            }
```

Please suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: Do your SqlDbType's match the type's in the DB?

Comment: you need to parse the values to their correct types, not use the text values etc

Comment: Run it in the debugger and see what the value of `ddlNgoName.SelectedValue` and `txtExpenseCat.Text` are.  Is `expense_category_name` really an `int`?

Comment: @Aaron: I had written wrong DB type for `expense_category_name` it was `nvarchar`

Comment: @DStanley: Yes, I checked it and it was the only problem, Now it is working for me

Comment: @Nadeem good.  In that case I've voted to close the question as a typographical error.

Comment: @DStanley: Yes sure, but I guess.This might also help some less technical people like me to understand where we can make mistakes and can learn from these type of posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these two lines you are saying that your parameter are Integers, but the first line tries to assign an object value and the second line tries to assign a string value. Something need to be fixed there

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@NgoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
                   ddlNgoName.SelectedValue;
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@expense_category_name", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
                    txtExpenseCat.Text;
```

For example these seems more appropriate given the field names

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@NgoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
                   Convert.ToInt32(ddlNgoName.SelectedValue);

cmd1.Parameters.Add("@expense_category_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = 
                    txtExpenseCat.Text;
```

Comment: Actually I need to change the DB type for `@expense_category_name` as in the table it is mentioned as `nvarchar`.

Comment: Well, if you need an integer then you return the SqlDbType.Int and add a conversion on the TextBox.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I dont need integer. My logic was to add text for that column. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems that you use two `SqlCommand`. You don't need them both; try using one, like this:

```
conn.Open();
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        "Insert into tbl_expense_category (NgoId, expense_category_name, expense_category_description, active) values (@NgoId, @expense_category_name,  @expense_category_description, @active)",
        conn))
        {
                command.Parameters.Add("@NgoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlNgoName.SelectedValue);
                command.Parameters.Add("@expense_category_name", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtExpenseCat.Text);
                command.Parameters.Add("@expense_category_description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEspenseDesc.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkActive.Checked;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
conn.Close();
```

Second, you have to know that it is a good practice open the connection before the `using` directive, especially when you are sending more than 1 command to the database.

Third, you must use the value types correctly. Where you are using integers, assign integer values to the parameters.

I have edited the code for you.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Good catch on the extra command, but you don't have to open the connection before `using`.

Comment: You are right, I think it's a good practice. I will replace "must" with "it is nice to" :)

Comment: Why do you think it's good practice?  The best practices I've seen (and what the examples on MSDN do) is to open the connection immediately before the command is executed.

Comment: Because if you use more commands against the data source, you open the connection, use the connection through 1 or more commands, and afterwards you close the connection.

Comment: Also I think that the best practice is to use `using` on the `SqlConnection` too. It is a lot easier to follow the code, operationally speaking.